# Binding between components ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6-classic

I have two components which interact with each other (binding).
They inside in one container and binding work fine, but when I want to reuse preview-email component in another container binding not work.
My code:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.mailings.MailingsEmailWizard', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
xtype: 'wizardemailmailing',
requires: ['Admin.view.mailings.MailingsEmailWizardModel'],

bodyPadding: 15,

height: '100%',

layout: 'card',

controller: 'wizardemailmailing',

viewModel: {
    type: 'wizardemailmailing'
},

defaults : {
    /*
     * Seek out the first enabled, focusable, empty textfield when the form is focused
     */
    defaultFocus: 'textfield:not([value]):focusable:not([disabled])',

    defaultButton : 'nextbutton'
},

items: [
    {
        xtype: 'container',
        itemId: 'mailingEmailContainer',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        viewModel: {
            type: 'wizardemailmailing'
        },
        width: '40%',
        defaults: {
            cls: 'mailing-email-container',
            margin: '0 20 20 0'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'edit-email'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'preview-email'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        xtype: 'import-contacts'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'preview-email'
    }
],
```

Please help me somebody.
My view looks like card and have 3 steps.

Comment: Try to removing inside `viewModel` with `mailingEmailContainer` and check it's working or not.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav Thank you it's work, but when I change viewModel from controller using this.getViewModel().set('logo', urls[0]) data in component not changing

Comment: Try to debug the code inside of controller may be value is not coming. something has missed

Comment: @NarendraJadhav I debug my code viewmodel have new value inside but in component he not change

Comment: ok Can you create working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)? so I will try to check the issue

Comment: @NarendraJadhav Yes I can. But it's to much code maybe I attach code for controller and component?

Comment: Ok do it *I attach code for controller and component*

Comment: @NarendraJadhav I found problem. All work fine, thank you for the help.
I forgot add bind property in component data(